# The asset “application.js” is not present in the asset pipeline in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I started new project with rails 7 and ruby 3 : rails new erdemsproject --css=bootstrap $rails g controller page index (after that in routes: root “home#index” )

$rails s

And I’m giving a basic error in localhost’s red page:
`The asset “application.js” is not present in the asset pipeline.` on the:

> <%= javascript_include_tag “application”, “data-turbo-track”:
> “reload”, defer: true %>

What is the mistake? I installed yarn, npm, npx and ruby again and again. But didn't solve.

Comment: Try to run `yarn build` in the terminal.

Comment: Dear Thomas, thanks for reply.  I tried "yarn build" in the terminal. And didn't solve.

Comment: Is `application.js` file present in `app/javascript/` folder?

Comment: yes it is present.

Answer (score 6):

in your app/views/layouts/applications.html.erb
instead of :

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

do :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/application.js", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

Comment: I got this same error when I created a new rails app with bootstrap as my css framework, whenever I visited the built up pages, I would get that error. I am using Rails 7 with Ruby 3.1.1 and Windows 10 OS without WSL, and got rid of the error with your suggestion, thank you @Chrispaix

Answer (score 4):

For a rails 7 app initialize with css flag you need to run your project with:

`./bin/dev`

Because you need to build your css and js with cssbundling-rails and jsbundling-rails.

Comment: Dear Pedro, thanks for your reply.  I'm new in rails 7. I couldn't understand the css flag issue. Can you explain more? Thanks in advance

Comment: Of course, is not a issue, is different way to run your website, in rails 7 you have two ways to handle assets, the default way using import map and the other way (in my opnion the best way) using this two new libraries cssbundling-rails and jsbundling-rails. For more information you can check this video from dhh: https://youtu.be/JsNtLiph87Y?t=281.

Comment: Now it works with rails s, but not js issues in bootstrap.  When i tried to use  ./bin/dev i got error like this:
erdem@erdem-VirtualBox:~/Masaüstü/railsProjects/deneme3$ ./bin/dev
Installing foreman...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/3.0.0 directory.

I don't know how can i solve.

Comment: Probably is a problem with foreman, try to install the gem before execute the script:
`gem install foreman`

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue for my Rails 7 project

Solution:

1. Add webpacker gem: `gem 'webpacker'`
2. Install webpacker from terminal: `rake webpacker:install`
3. Run command `yarn build`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the command

> rails new myapp -j webpack

to generate your app, and tried to use npm instead of yarn to install dependencies. webpack cannot compile the code generated.
By default, the files generated, in Procfile.dev, you have:

> `js: yarn build --watch`

either install yarn or if u want to use npm change this to:

> `js: npm run build -- --watch`

then run

> `npm install -D webpack-cli`
> the error should clear.